# recursive definition of a palindrome help

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, palindrome

1. Recall that a bit string is a string using the alphabet {0, 1}. A palindrome is a string that is equal to the reversal of itself. Consider the following recursive definition of a palindrome:
   Basis Step: λ (the empty string) is a palindrome.

Recursive Step: If w is a palindrome and x ∈ {0, 1}, then xwx is a palindrome.

There is a problem with this definition. Identify and state the problem. Then fix the problem by providing a new and correct recursive definition.

Comment: What's your question?  See what palindromes this definition generates.  Anything seem amiss?

Comment: The professor asks us to find the mistake of the definition that I show above. Then fix it to a correct definition of palindromes. Thank you.@mjqxxxx

Comment: Definition must generate _all_ palindromes in order to be well-defined. Can you find any palindrome that this definition can not generate?

Comment: Yes. I find it cannot generate like 515 etc. Thank you. How to fix it ?@Alistair

Comment: You'll never generate 515 even with the correct definition, because 5 isn't in your alphabet. However, I'll give some steps to a solution in an answer.

Comment: It cannot generate 11611 right ? @ConMan

Comment: Again, 6 is not in the alphabet. But you can't generate, for example, 11011, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try generating palindromes using the given definition, you'll get a set that looks something like: $\{\lambda, 00, 11, 0000, 1001, 0110, 1111, 000000, 100001, 010010, 110011, 001100, 101101, 011110, 111111, \dots \}$. In fact, all of the strings in this list have an even length. The reason why should be pretty clear - you're starting with a 0-length string, and always adding 2 more bits. So you'll never reach an odd-length string like $101$.

What are the shortest odd-length palindromes? They're the single bits, $0$ and $1$. You definitely can't reach them from the basis and the given recursion rule, so you either have to change the basis or the recursion to include them in the set. Which one makes more sense?

Comment: I understand. If i want to include them in the set, i just need to add If w is a palindrome and x ∈ {0, 1}, then xwxx is a palindrome into the recursion. Right ? Thank You.

Comment: @chenCrush, not exactly. Your addition makes $10011$ palindrome which is not. Note the answer; "you're starting with a 0-length string, and always adding 2 more bits.". This gives you _all_ even-length strings. What should you do to generate _all_ odd-length strings?

Comment: @Alistair  Change it to wxw? Thank you.

Comment: @chenCrush, that is the given incomplete definition. Think about adding to the base case since it's more easier. What should you add in order to include _all_ odd-length strings?

Comment: @Alistair add λ(1-length string)  is a palindrome?

Comment: @chenCrush, yes.

Comment: @Alistair Thank you so much.